# How to update a chart with data coming from an API endpoint in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, svelte

I am using the [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) JS web framework with the [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) charting library to plot a bar chart. I have created a *Skeleton project* and installed the `svelte-chartjs` and the `chart.js` packages:

```bash
npm install svelte-chartjs chart.js
```

Under the `routes` folder, I made the `generate/+server.js` endpoint to simulate the API calls:

```js
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

export function GET() {
  let randomNumbers = Array.from({ length: 12 }, () => getRandomNumber(10, 20));

  return json(randomNumbers);
}
```

It generates 12 random integer numbers between 10 and 20. Now, I can call this endpoint using the `fetch('/generate')` function on the root page. The content of the `routes/+page.svelte` file is the following:

```html
<script>
  import { Bar } from 'svelte-chartjs';
  import { Chart, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js';

  Chart.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale);

  let fetchedData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

  let data = {
    labels: [
      'January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December'
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Random Number',
        data: fetchedData,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(98,  182, 239,0.4)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(98,  182, 239, 1)',
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    ]
  };

  let options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  };

  async function generate() {
    const response = await fetch('/generate');
    fetchedData = await response.json();
  }
</script>

<h1>Fetch Data from API endpoint</h1>

<button on:click={generate}>Request</button>

<p>Current data: {fetchedData}</p>

<div>
  <Bar {data} {options} />
</div>
```

I have initialized the data with 1 to 12 integers, which is changed when clicking the <kbd>Request</kbd> button. Therefore, the data fetching is successful however the bar chart is not updated with the newly generated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the chart with newly generated data, you need to reactively declare the `data` variable:

```html
$: data = {
    labels: [
      'January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December'
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Random Number',
        data: fetchedData,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(98,  182, 239,0.4)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(98,  182, 239, 1)',
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    ]
  };
```

Because the state of the bar charts needs to be recomputed whenever the button component changes the data state. It essentially means that "re-run this code whenever any of the referenced values change" in this case the `datasets[0].data` values. For more information, visit the [Reactivity / Declarations](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations) tutorial.

Try out the complete code here: [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/00c5f82018344ea1a8ab1a9f4d173cb8?version=3.55.1)

[image]